# Transferring between Pudong International Airport and Hongqiao International Airport

Tags: china, transportation, shanghai

I am arriving from London via an Air China flight in Pudong at 6:45 a.m. and have an Air China flight to Shenzhen that departs from Hongqiao at 11:30 a.m. I understand that there's a shuttle service between these airports that leaves every half an hour.

Is this information up to date and is it still the best way to do this transfer? And additionally, will I then be entering China in Shanghai itself or am I still airside? Lastly, is there anything to keep in mind?

Comment: As a general note, Shanghai Metro Line 2 connects the airports as well. If you weren't traveling during AM rush hour I'd recommend that.

Comment: And if you feel like doing something crazy, you can take the maglev for a short hop and continue with Metro Line 2 from there.

Comment: For the record: your second leg is domestic so you will *always* pass immigration at your first stop. The only question is whether you can remain airside which seems unlikely given the distance between the airports.

Comment: Ah thank you all. I'm gonna be a really boring person and take the shuttle :)

Comment: I see this question is pre-COVID. Just for the note, you can't do this currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this information is still correct.

It is mentioned on the [airport website](https://www.shairport.com/enpdjc/jcjt/index_228241037.html):

> **Airport Line 1 to Hongqiao Traffic Hub East Center
> Service hours:**

- Shanghai Terminal 1: 07:00 am to 11:00 pm
- Shanghai Terminal 2: 07:05 am to 11:05 pm

> Frequency: Every 15-25 minutes
> Fares: CNY 30.00.

You will be exiting the airport and you won’t stay airside when transiting.